# List Amplify Subscription Cancel with different Device

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

We have 2 flutter mobile apps. In 1 application we create subscription with amplify and in the other application we listen to the update method.

If the application we create subscription crashes due to any problem or if we close the application with hard close, the second application listening to the update is stuck on that screen. So subscription is not cancelled.

Is there any way to listen to this or not to cancel it?